# Calling a java method from shell over T3 protocol

Tags: java, shell, unix, weblogic

I am trying to create a batch system for my project at school and I don't exactly know where or how to start, I want to do a bash script that will call a java method (what happens next in the java code doesn't matter) the java method will be on a WebLogic server deployed remotely. How can I use T3 protocol to call a java method ?

Answer (score 1):

Well you could create a servlet and do a http get / post request and thus invoke the relevant method if that helps.